# Composer file error when providing ports as a string

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I try to run the following `docker-compose` file, I get the following error:

> wordpress.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array
>   phpmyadmin.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array
>   phpmyadmin.environment contains an invalid type, it should be an
>   object, or an array

```
wordpress:
image: wordpress
links: "wordpress_db:mysql"
ports: "8080:80"

wordpress_db:
image: mariadb
environment: "MY_SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: niti"

phpmyadmin:
image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
links: "wordpress_db:mysql"
ports: "8181:80"
environment: "MY_SQL_USERNAME: root"
environment: "MY_SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: niti"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid type error in Docker Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960226/invalid-type-error-in-docker-compose)

Comment: yml files are whitespace sensitive, and you should have a version number in there (version 1 is long since deprecated). Please update your question with a complete example and corrected indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links: "wordpress_db:mysql"
  ports: 
    - "8080:80"

wordpress_db:
  image: mariadb
  environment: "MY_SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: niti"

phpmyadmin:
  image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
  links: "wordpress_db:mysql"
  ports: 
    - "8181:80"
  environment: "MY_SQL_USERNAME: root"
  environment: "MY_SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: niti"`
```

It expects a list of array, so you should provide a list: it detect a list by adding the `-` before the ports string

Answer (score 2):

Your compose file had formatting issues, it expects a list as an input & not maps. I have fixed it momentarily -

```
version: "3"

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    links:
      - wordpress_db
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

  wordpress_db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      - MY_SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=niti

  phpmyadmin:
    image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
    links:
      - wordpress_db:mysql
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    environment:
      - MY_SQL_USERNAME=root
      - MY_SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=niti
```

Comment: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.wordpress.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array
services.phpmyadmin.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array
services.wordpress.links contains an invalid type, it should be an array
services.phpmyadmin.links contains an invalid type, it should be an array

Comment: I doubt if the code is copied correctly. It works fine for me.